# Big O estimate for summing up an array

Tags: computer-science, big-o

If I have an array of 1 million integers.
Summing it up is considered O(n) because I have to perfom n-1 add operations.
Correct ?

Comment: This sort of question is probably better suited for http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @joshi: I don't know. I think this is a perfect SO question, and stackexchange is fragmenting too much...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can add two elements in O(1) then summing n elements takes O(n), yes.  If they may take longer, then no.  For example, if all of the elements are unsigned 32-bit integers but you want the exact sum (not the sum mod 2<sup>32</sup>) then it may be as large as n · (2<sup>32</sup> − 1) in which case summing will take O(n log n).

Answer (score 3):

Yes. That's exactly correct.

Of course, there may be special cases where it's less. And certain methods could make it smaller, but those methods have a greater overhead than addition.

For example, if you know the values are from 1 to n, that's O(1) because you can compute n*(n+1)/2. But the general case is O(n).

Comment: Calculating n*(n-1)/2 takes O(log n), not O(1).

Comment: How do you figure? It's a few multiplications divisions and a subtraction. Regardless of n, it will take the same amount of time if there's no overflow.

Comment: It is O(1), if n was 1, it would take the same amount of time to calculate n*(n+1)/2 as when n would equal 1 million.  Therefore it is not dependent on N: O(1) time [constant]

Comment: No that is completely wrong. If he has an array of 1000000 entries then summing it up is O(1). It is only if he has an array of n entries that summing it up is O(n). (to clarify - your answer to the question, not the debate about n*(n-1)/2)

Comment: My assumption was that 1000000 was an example, and he's looking for the general case for n elements given that he stated n-1 additions.

Comment: @Bob, JoshD: I can calculate n*(n-1)/2 for n = 1 in about 5 nanoseconds. For n = 2^1000000, it takes 6,600,000 nanoseconds. Do you really want to argue that this is O(1)? n is about lg n bits, and n(n-1)/2 is about 2 lg n bits. It's hard to output 2 lg n bits in O(1).

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, it takes O((log n)^2) with schoolbook and O((log n)^(1 + epsilon)) with FFT-based methods.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because the time used for summing is direct variation to the number of elements `n`.